Double-superscript error in a formula
I wrote the following formula in Overleaf.
${\mathbf{{\ddot{r}^{opt}_\star}}^\mathbf{T}}$

I can see the result I want in the preview:

But when I compile it, it prompts an error: Double superscript.
How can I achieve this result?

please provide code we can compile to reproduce the error. never post images of code: copy code and errors as text. images can't be searched, can't be tested and can't be read by screen-readers. also, overleaf is just your editor, so please choose tags relevant to the actual issue (which isn't with overleaf).

Give $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\star}^{\,\mathbf{opt}^{\mathbf{T}}}$ a try. If "opt" and "T" are supposed to be in upright-nonbold, change the formula to $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\star}^{\,\mathrm{opt}^{\mathrm{T}}}$.

Please also provide more information about the structure of the formula: Is T supposed to be a superscript attached to \ddot{\mathbf{r}^{opt}_\star}, or is supposed to be a superscript attached to opt? Incidentally, do note that \mathbf should not encompass \ddot, as \mathbf operates only on Latin-alphabet letters, not on symbols.

@cfr - I've adjusted the posting's tags.

"T" means "Transpose", and both superscripts and subscripts are part of "r".

My issue has been resolved. Thank you all for your active responses!

Your code doesn't logically reflect the structure of the formula you want to typeset. You've attached two distinct superscripts to the r rather than having the second be a superscript attached to the first superscript.
Perhaps you want
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
${\mathbf{{\ddot{r}^{{opt}^\mathbf{T}}_\star}}}$
\end{document}



is it meant to be all in bold? I have absolutely zero idea what this represents ....

With stacked superscripts (and stacked subscripts too), there's almost always some ambiguity as to the logical order or precedence. It's often wise to add explicit parentheses to clarify which superscript does what.

If both opt (better: \mathrm{opt}) and T equally modify \ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\star}, the third form in the upper row of the screenshot may be best suited to signal this state.
Adding some subtle kerning -- in the form of half-width positive and negative thin-spaces -- may help with the overall readability.
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{document}

$\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\star}^{(\mathrm{opt}^{\mathrm{T}})}$
\quad
${(\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\star}^{\mathrm{opt}})}^{\!\mathrm{T}}$
\quad
$\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\star}^{\mathrm{opt},\mathrm{T}}$

\medskip
with some kerning:
$\ddot{\mathbf{r}}_{\mkern-1.5mu\star}^{\mkern1.5mu\mathrm{opt},\mathrm{T}}$

\end{document}


Why does it happen? Because your \mathbf{{\ddot{r}^{opt}_\star} becomes a single Accent atom and, by rule, when TeX finds a single Accent atom, pairs of braces enclosing it are removed.
You might solve the issue by typing
${{}\mathbf{{\ddot{r}^{opt}_\star}}}^\mathbf{T}$

(note the {} and the braces surrounding the empty subformula and the Accent atom), but the output would be

I don't think this is what you want.

The second derivative symbol should be over \mathbf{r}, not the other way around.
Should “opt” be bold? I don't think so.
Should the symbol for transposition be bold and upright? I don't think so.

Better syntax:
${{}\ddot{\mathbf{r}}^{\mathrm{opt}}_{\star}}^{T}$

This would print

Really ambiguous, isn't it? Does the T refer to “opt”, perhaps?
If you want to transpose the second derivative of ropt⋆ (sorry for the bad rendering), then use parentheses:
$(\ddot{\mathbf{r}}^{\mathrm{opt}}_{\star})^{T}$


